# Taxonomy Tag Conditionals

Tags: taxonomy, tags, conditional-tags, jigoshop

I'm using jigoshop as main ecommerce plugin.

Jigoshop use Taxonomies call, product_cat and product_tag.

In my theme I use a default (h5bp) 404.php, so every time a tag doesn't exist I get the default 404.

But I need to have a special template that give a `THIS TAG DO NOT EXIST`

how can I do this?

I'm using pointless:

```
@@@
<?php

if (is_tax()){
    jigoshop_get_template( 'product_taxonomy-no.php' );
}else{
 jigoshop_get_template( 'product_taxonomy-no.php' );
}
?>
@@@
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an entirely different template, you could filter `404_template` and check query vars for a specific taxonomy:

```
function wpa83050_404_template( $template = '' ){
    global $wp_query;
    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) )
        $template = locate_template( array( "product_taxonomy-no.php", $template ), false );
    return $template;
}
add_filter( '404_template', 'wpa83050_404_template' );
```

You could also just put logic similar to the above in your 404 template and use that single template for all 404s, check `$wp_query` for what query vars are set and print some text accordingly. add `var_dump( $wp_query );` to your template to see what query vars get set under different conditions.